# How to make changes to a site already hosted on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I hosted a site in Github pages by going to setting of my repo. But I wanna change the Title tag in HTML. I tried Pushing from my local machine, but the changes are not updated in the githubpages site.

Comment: Change the page _in your repository_, commit, push the changed page.  It will be shown within a few minutes.